# Linux font equivalent for symbol and wingdings

Tags: java, linux, fonts, aspose.words

I am using aspose words for java 20.6 and try to build a pdf from docx in linux. The docx-document has an unordered list with bulletpoints. These bulletpoints use the symbol font.

When i create the pdf with aspose these bulletpoints are shown in webdings font as a clapperboard.

I did not find any free font (for commercial use) that is an equivalent to the symbol font. Does anyone know a good solution to show correct bulletpoints in my unordered list?

I found the way to substitute fonts, but i don't know which font to use:

```
TableSubstitutionRule tableSubstitutionRule = fontSettings.getSubstitutionSettings().getTableSubstitution();
tableSubstitutionRule.addSubstitutes("Symbol", "?WHICH_FONT?");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check Google's [Noto Sans Symbol](https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-zsym) font. Noto fonts are free, but I am not sure about commercial use.

Comment: According to the Noto home page:
"All Noto fonts are licensed under the Open Font License. You can use them in all your products & projects — print or digital, commercial or otherwise."